Verifying the eigenvectors of Grover Operation Q in Brassard's Amplitude Amplification and Estimation
This question is regarding Brassard's et al. Quantum Amplitude Amplification and Estimation (arXiv).
Specifically, I fail to understand why $|\Psi_\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigl( \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}|\Psi_1\rangle \pm \frac{i}{\sqrt{1-a}}|\Psi_0\rangle \Bigr)$ are the eigenvectors of $Q$ in $H_\Psi$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_\pm = e^{\pm i 2\theta}$.
I tried to verify that $Q |\Psi_+\rangle = e^{i2\theta} |\Psi_+\rangle$, by calculating $Q |\Psi_+\rangle$ using Lemma 1 which states that:
\begin{align*}
Q |\Psi_1\rangle &= (1-2a) |\Psi_1\rangle - 2a |\Psi_0\rangle \\
Q |\Psi_0\rangle &= 2(1-a) |\Psi_1\rangle + (1-2a) |\Psi_0\rangle
\end{align*}
Now, by linearity we can calculate
\begin{align*}
Q |\Psi_+\rangle
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigl( 
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} Q|\Psi_1\rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt{1-a}}Q|\Psi_0\rangle
\Bigr) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigl(
    \frac{(1-2a) |\Psi_1\rangle - 2a |\Psi_0\rangle}{\sqrt{a}} +
    i\frac{2(1-a) |\Psi_1\rangle + (1-2a) |\Psi_0\rangle}{\sqrt{1-a}}
\Bigr) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigl[
    \Bigl(
        \frac{1-2a}{\sqrt{a}}|\Psi_1\rangle + \frac{i(1-2a)}{\sqrt{1-a}}|\Psi_0\rangle
    \Bigr) +
    \Bigl(
    i\frac{2(1-a)}{\sqrt{1-a}}|\Psi_1\rangle + \frac{-2a}{\sqrt{a}}|\Psi_0\rangle
    \Bigr)
\Bigr] \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigl[
    \Bigl(
        \frac{1-2a}{\sqrt{a}}|\Psi_1\rangle + \frac{i(1-2a)}{\sqrt{1-a}}|\Psi_0\rangle
    \Bigr) +
    \Bigl(
    i\frac{-2a}{\sqrt{1-a}}|\Psi_1\rangle + \frac{-2a}{\sqrt{a}}|\Psi_0\rangle
    \Bigr) +
    \Bigl(
        \frac{2i}{\sqrt{1-a}}|\Psi_1\rangle
    \Bigr)
\Bigr]
\end{align*}
which I don't see how it progresses us.

Note: this might be related to my other question regarding this paper


The maths is a little bit cleaner if you calculate the eigenvalues of Q directly from its definition,
$$A  = $$
$$=\sin(\theta)|\chi_1\rangle\langle0| + \cos(\theta)|\chi_0\rangle\langle0|$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( e^{j\theta_a} |{\chi_+}\rangle\langle0| + e^{-j\theta_a} |{\chi_-}\rangle \langle 0| \in \mathcal{H}^\psi$$
Where $|{\chi+}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|{\chi_0}\rangle -j|{\chi_1}\rangle),$ and $ |{\chi-}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|{\chi_0}\rangle + j|{\chi_1}\rangle)$ by eulers formula.
$$S_\chi = |\chi_+\rangle \langle\chi_-| + | \chi_- \rangle\langle \chi_+|$$
$$S_0 = -I$$
$$\implies Q = -AS_0A^\dagger S_x = e^{2j\theta}|\chi_+\rangle\langle\chi_+| + e^{-2j\theta} |\chi_-\rangle\langle\chi_-|$$
And so we have the eigenvalues and eigenvectors that you're looking for.
Edit: you may want to look at page 5. near eqn. (1) of the Brassard et. al. paper to get a good definition of what 'good' and 'bad' states are for the $S_x$ operator.

Thank you for the answer @Billy Ballico! However, I don't quite follow.


Probably should it be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the definitions of $|\chi_\pm\rangle$?


Why is $S_0 = -I$? Can't $|0\rangle \in H_\Psi$? Also, if it would be $-I$, wouldn't it mean that $Q = -A (-I) A^\dagger S_x = A A^\dagger S_x = S_x$?



Ah yep, my apologies, I used some shorthand in the state loading operator, typically people project the entire operator into the state space where this is true (i.e. ancilla = 0), which is what I've done above. but obviously for the operator to actually be unitary it has to map the other computational states as well.
Consider however you do the opposite say you project into ancilla = 1 for example, as you say in this case $Q = -A (I)A^\dagger S_x = - S_x$.
As for the factors of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ I have just dropped them out.
